# Have a user upload an image to the Android Resources/drawable folder

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need the user to be able to upload an image, and then have the image be able to be accessed later for drawing it. I only know how to show an image in the Android Resources/drawable folder. I don't think it is possible for a user to upload an image there, so is there another place they can upload it, and then have the image to be used? I don't know how to have the user to be able to upload it either.

I only know how to show an image with the xaml code `<Image Source="image.png"/>`, where image.png is in the Android Resources/drawable folder

Comment: Resources is not writable at runtime.  You can save a file to any user writable path and reference it later as an ImageSource.  Where is the user "uploading" an image from in the first place?

Comment: @Jason I need the user to be able to upload an image from their images folder, the photos that they have taken. I don't know where to have them upload it either.

Comment: "upload" usually implies transferring to a remote server.  Is that what you mean?  Just accessing images from the users gallery can be done with the Media plugin: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: @Jason I think he wants the user to input an image and have it stored on the device

Comment: @Jason WhiteFire356 is correct.

Comment: again, use the Media plugin.

Comment: @Jason the only problem is that I have to have other data attached to the picture. I would have to be able to save strings too in something like a text file.

Comment: So create a database to store this other data along with the path of the image.  Or just write it to a text file if you prefer.

Comment: @Jason can you tell me how to write it to a text file? I will research this

Comment: just use normal C# I/O - like `File.WriteAllText()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Resources contained in out raw directory of our project will be packaged inside our APK and will not be writeable at runtime.

So I highly recommend that you use [Internal](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) or [External](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) Data Storage to store your images and text file.

For more details, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/

And at the bottom of this page:[External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows), there is a example which function is to save text file in External storage, it should be helpful for you.

The sample link is here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/LocalFiles

If you want to choose Photos and Video, you can use [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) of jamesmontemagno. Of course , you can achieve this function yourself.